# deny access for subfolders on my web_page

Tags: .htaccess, web

So I just create a web page and it's online but if someone writhe this in the address bar:

mypage.com/css or mypage.com/js

it shows them al the files in a list pr something.

how can I deny access to that, like one of those access forbidden pages or a nothing to see here page.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an htaccess file in your document root with this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

See the [`Options` directive documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much this was killing me :)